# Добрый день. Вопрос по git и виртуальному окружению

Tags: python

Подскажите, что делать вначале: Создавать виртуальные окружение или инициализировать git?

Comment: примерно как "что делать вначале - бутерброд или чай?"

Answer (score 1):

Это не связанные между собой процессы. Разве что делайте так, чтобы директория виртуального окружения, если она в проекте, не попала в индексацию гитом. Это делается с помощью файла .gitignore.
На практике обычно имеется уже инициилизованный гитом проект и уже в нем создается виртуальное окружение